# Apply styling only to first page sticky posts

Tags: loop, sticky-post

I'm using the following bit of code to highlight sticky posts:

```
<?php if (is_sticky()) : ?>

    <div class="col-md-12 box-01">
    <div class="content">

<?php endif; ?>
```

The only thing is, I only want to highlight the stickies that show at the *top* of the page... not when they're repeated further down the list of posts.

For example, I noticed that when I click the 'Next' link to go to the next page or posts, the stickies show up again. And because of my code, they're highlighted with the new styles in the same way as they are at the top.

Is there any kind of tag I can use to target sticky posts but *only* those that are stuck at the top? Rather than those further down?

I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that stickies aren't completely unset from the main loop on paged pages but only on the first page. If we look at [the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3717), we will see that stickies are only unset from the main loop if they are on the first page. So we have two options here depending on what you exactly need

### OPTION 1

If you need to keep your stickies in the loop on paged pages and just remove the styling, you can make use of the `is_paged()` condition in conjuction with your condition

```
if (    is_sticky()
     && !is_paged()
) {
    // Add your styling here
}
```

### OPTION 2.1

Completely remove stickies from paged pages

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && $q->is_paged()      // Only target paged pages
    ) {
        // Remove stickies
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );
    }
});
```

I'm just thinking that if we use this option that we will need to adjust `$found_posts` to compensate for pagination on the first page. `WP_Query` throws us a curveball here as we cannot set `post__not_in` on page one as this will explicitely remove any sticky post from the sticky posts array if these specific posts aren't on the first page.

I will investigate this and post anything extra that would be relevant to this issue

**EDIT**

There is an issue with pagination, so we will need to adjust the `$found_posts` property to adjust for pagination

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', function( $found_posts, \WP_Query $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
         && !$q->is_paged()
    ) {
        // Get the sticky posts array
        $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

        // Get all the post ID's from the first page
        $ids = $q->posts;

        // Remove all the current ids from the current sticky posts array
        $stickies = array_diff( $stickies, $ids );

        $found_posts = $found_posts - count( $stickies );
    }

    return $found_posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### OPTION 2.2

I always tend to use the following right off the back to handle my sticky posts. This completely removes sticky posts from the main query and then it gets added back to via the `the_posts` filter

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'ignore_sticky_posts', 1                            );
        $q->set( 'post__not_in',        get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) );

        add_filter( 'the_posts', function( $posts, \WP_Query $q )
        {
            // Only do this for the first page
            if ( $q->is_paged() )
                return $posts;

            $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
            // Check if we have stickies
            if ( !$stickies )
                return $posts;

            $args = [
                'posts_per_page' => count( $stickies ),
                'post__in'       => $stickies,
            ];
            $sticky_posts = get_posts( $args );

            // Merge the array
            $posts = array_merge( $sticky_posts, $posts );

            return $posts;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }
});
```